# Insert google map showing my current location

Tags: google-maps, position, location

I  am traveling globally and need to insert a Google map on my web page that shows my current position (not the position of the reader) so that others can see where I am.

Does anyone have a straightforward solution to do this. I know how to use My Places to create maps and insert in my pages, but have avoided having to get involved in using the Maps API so far.  I have some knowledge of  HTML and Javascript, but it is minimal so would rather avoid this if I can.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Do you want to be able to track yourself while walking around or driving or just a static location of where you are?

Comment: Also answered over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718998/share-my-current-location-with-the-world-publicly/43719290#43719290

Answer (score 1):

Further to my answer over at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718998/share-my-current-location-with-the-world-publicly/43719290#43719290) you may find bits of this example useful: - [hypoCampus](https://hypocampus.applications.uwa.edu.au/)

The little blue man/person/icon follows your location. If you scroll the maps away you can then press the static blue map-control man to re-center on your location. When you're moving (throttled location update is changing) the icon is walking otherwise it is standing.

(There's a bug with Manifest - "display" : "standalone" at the mo [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716686&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=))

Hopefully Firebase have committed to bypassing the speed-humps of W3C/IETF and will give us ServiceWorker Background Geolocation tracking very soon.

Comment: 22hr's until I can award the bounty :D

Comment: Cheers. Not too fussed about the bounty. Thanks anyway. For those wanting to run hypoCampus make sure you have Location services enabled and grant the App access. Also you cannot have private browsing on as localStorage is required. And finally, with Chrome, Opera, or Samsung browsers Add to Homescreen for improved experience. Next version of Chrome (or n+1) the Web App will appear as a first class App. (Like Firefox when they still had the registerApp methods)

Answer (score -1):

you must tell to map your current location. for that you must get your location Latitude  and Longitude for show that by maps.

get that by :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=+" + MapAddress + "&sensor=false
```

try this html code in your page. str_lat and str_lng are your location :

```
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false>
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(str_lat,str_lng);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:'Location!'
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map-canvas'/>
  </body>
</html>;
```

Answer (score -2):

See Here  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

and see this code for judging your skills  don't worry about new terms they are explained in the link above

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```