# Share my current location with the world publicly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location

I'd like to create a website where I share MY current location with the world, I've been reading about [this](https://blog.google/products/maps/share-your-trips-and-real-time-location-google-maps/) all morning but I can't see a way to embed this into a website so it's publicly view able, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your common URL redirect to your latest coordinates such as: -
https://www.google.com/maps/place/-31.8878269,115.8162218/@-31.8878269,115.8162218,17z

IOW specify the Lon/Lat coords in the URL as parameters.

If you were to go for a more extensive solution then I suggest server intelligence would be required to keep a database of your (and your friends?) current location. A change could be polled from interested clients or a specific event could be pushed from the server and subscribed to in a client ServiceWorker.

If you choose this path then you will inevitably be confronted by the conumdrum that Web Apps can't track geolocation unless in the foreground and the phone is not asleep. So if you wanted your ski buddies to see which piste you're on or your cycling/jogging mates to see your progress then W3C/IETF flat-out refuse to acknowledge your very existence let alone your requirements/business case :-(

[Exhibit A](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745)

[Exhibit B](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=383125)

Comment: Thanks @McMurphy this makes perfect sense I just didn't want to admit it to myself, I may have to put together a APK and pol it to a server which then pulls it into the map, I also put a bounty on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512179/insert-google-map-showing-my-current-location if you want to answer it aswell :D

Comment: If you go the Push APi/Notification route to inform you clients of location update(s) then I suggest using Firebase Cloud Messaging https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple this way clients can subscribe to "Topics" and not have to map server/client subscriptions at the application level. Sadly, W3C/IETF have dumbed-down the web-push specification to meet the vagaries of Mozilla's failing Autopush.

Answer (score 1):

I work at [HyperTrack](http://hypertrack.com), and we have a few FREE solutions you could use.

1. HyperTrack Live, an Android (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.hypertrack.sendeta&hl=en) and iOS (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hypertrack-live/id1076924821?mt=8) app which allows you to share your location and destination which your friends can follow right along with via a private link you share with them.
2. HyperTrack API/SDK, which allows you to create an application (or use one of the example apps we've open sourced at http://github.com/hypertrack) that contains our FREE SDK and then it will just follow you where you go and you can use a widget to embed into your website. Our SDK is very battery efficient and uses less than 10% while actively tracking all day.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Yes it is possible,you can extract the location values of a device that travels all the way. At first the latitude and longitude values of a device location has to be tracked it can done in android by listening to OnLocationUpdate() method,that provides the location values for a certain interval. Then you have to handle the location and send it to the receiver device then plot the updated location in Maps..

On the other hand the execution of sharing your location with anyone can be done by integrating a reliable SDK [TELIVER](https://teliver.io)
    TELIVER SDK provides you a realtime location sharing feature. The SDK can be easily integrated in Android or IOS Application the users can be registered as CONSUMER or OPERATOR. The user who is registered as a CONSUMER can share his location with a trackingID to anyone. And who all having the trackingId can track the user location in maps.

[Live Tracking Made Easier](https://teliver.io)